# PHP- Use the folder location of remote included file as the current working directory

Tags: php

I have a remote php file(B.php) which I am including in another file(A.php) in my local by `include("remote_path/B.php")`. But when I execute A.php, all the scripts I have in B.php are executed in the context of A.php.

For example

```
file_put_contents("test.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
```

in B.php but the new file test.txt is created in the folder where I have A.php.

Is there any way to change the execution context to the directory of B.php?

Answer (score 0):

This is how PHP works. 
You can use `__DIR__` for specifying the path.

From :http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

> `__DIR__`: The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

Try this in your B.php

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/test.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
```